# How can i sum two property values iterating through the properties of an object? js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object in which every property it has an array as a value and inside another object:

```
  products: {
        product1Options: [{ itemName: "", itemRate: 0, itemAmount: 0 }],
        product2Options: [{ itemName: "", itemRate: 0, itemAmount: 0 }],
        product3Options: [{ itemName: "", itemRate: 0, itemAmount: 0 }],
        },
```

In some inputs i change the value of the 0's and I need to multiply the itemRate and itemAmount in each object inside each array. So I made this:

```
 if (this.products.product1Options.length ||
            this.products.product2Options.length ||
            this.products.product3Options.length) {

            for(let prop in this.products) {
                prop.map((obj) => {
                     
                if(obj.itemRate > 0 && obj.itemAmount > 0 ) {
                    let sum = 0;
                    return sum += prop.itemRate * prop.itemAmount;
                }
                })
            }; }
```

But i get prop.map is not a function, i realized that's because prop is actually an object prop. So how could i do to achieve what im needing here. If anyone could help me i will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for..in loop iterates over the properties of an object not its values. So inside your loop, `prop` is just a string. You can either do

```
for(let prop in this.products) {
  this.products[prop].map((obj) => {
    if(obj.itemRate > 0 && obj.itemAmount > 0 ) {
      let sum = 0;
      return sum += prop.itemRate * prop.itemAmount;
    }
  })
 };
```

or

```
for(let prop in Object.values(this.products)) {
  // .map returns an array but you are not doing anything with it
  prop.map((obj) => {
    if(obj.itemRate > 0 && obj.itemAmount > 0 ) {
      let sum = 0; // This var is not helping since it gets reset to 0 every time
      return sum += prop.itemRate * prop.itemAmount;
    }
    // when you get here you don't return anything
  })
 };
```

But also it doesn't seem like you are using the map function properly, at times you are returning `undefined` when the `if` condition is not met. And you are not really doing anything with the array returned by the mapping. If what you care about is the sum of each product either you declare sum outside of the loop or you use `reduce`

```
for (let prop in this.products) {
  const sum = this.products[prop].reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item.itemRate > 0 && item.itemAmount > 0) {
      return acc + item.itemRate * item.itemAmount;
    }
    return acc;
  }, 0);
  // do something with sum
}
```

To be honest though that `if` check doesn't seem to be that useful since if they are both 0 you only add 0 to a sum. So you can simplify like this:

```
for (let prop in this.products) {
  // If you are not familiar with reduce go check it out! What we do here
  // is reducing an array to a single value. We initialize it with 0 and for
  // each item in the array we add the rate * amount to the previous sum
  const sum = this.products[prop].reduce((prevSum, item) => prevSum + item.itemRate * item.itemAmount, 0);
}
```

I then assume you do something with that sum. If you want the final total you would have something like this:

```
let totalSum = 0;
for (let prop in this.products) {
  totalSum += this.products[prop].reduce((prevSum, item) => prevSum + item.itemRate * item.itemAmount, 0);
}
```

Technically you can go one step further and do all of it with one reduce only but I will let you figure that out. Keep in mind that readability is important! Don't feel like you HAVE to use reduce if you are not comfortable with it, I just wanted to show you what was possible but you can achieve the same in many other ways in JS.